# How to make number of template parameters less in calling?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function with a member function pointer as template parameter

```
template<
    class Object,
    class Property,
    void (Object::*setProperty)(Property const&)
>
void f(Object& object, Property const& property)
```

Every time, I have to call the function with 3 template parameters as following

```
f<A, Value, &A::setValue>(a, value);
```

Any way to make the number of template parameter less by using tempalte parameter derivation or other techniques

```
f<&A::setValue>(a, value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first thought was "no", but then I realized there is sort of a wierd way:

```
template<class Object, class Property>
struct APointlessName { //needs a better name, but I can't think of one right away
    APointlessName(Object& object, Property const& property)
    :object(&object), property(&property)
    {}

    template<void (Object::*setProperty)(Property const&)>
    void with() 
    {
        Object& object = *(this->object);
        Property const& property= *(this->property);
        //your function code goes here
    }

    Object* object;
    Property const* property;
};
template< class Object, class Property>
APointlessName<Object,Property> f(Object& object, Property const& property)
{return APointlessName<Object,Property>(object, property);}
```

and then the usage would be like this:

```
f(a, value).with<&A::setValue>();
```

Definitely a little weird, but it does avoid the explicit types.  Hopefully someone else thinks of a better way.

Comment: Heh, I like this. Sneaky.